# Sql LEFT JOIN returns multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my query

```
SELECT items.title
, genre.genre 
FROM `items` 
LEFT JOIN `genre` 
ON genre.item_id = items.item_id
```

it returns result as

Title       Genre
Title1      Genre1
Title1      Genre2
Title2      Genre2

but i want result as

Title       Genre
Title1      Genre1,Genre2
Title2      Genre2

### UPDATE

my items table
[Items table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duBeE.png)
my genre table
[genre table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOJsk.png)

```
"SELECT items.title, GROUP_CONCAT(genre.genre) as genres FROM `items` LEFT JOIN `genre` ON genre.item_id = items.item_id"
```

it now returns

Title1  Genre1,Genre2

but my second row of items table does not have any row in genre table.But it should return second row too as i am using LEFT JOIN. but it does not return second row

Comment: Look into `group_concat`.

Comment: it works but it does not return all rows of left table

Comment: it hides those with null in right table

Comment: Please update your question with your new SQL and the results it is giving you (plus the source data if it differs from what you’ve already supplied)

Comment: use *group_concat* with conditional checks

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3VKEf7GcUgGQDJvfPUiMcN/0 check this out, is this what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT i.title, GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre)
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN genre g ON g.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY i.title
```

Note that I used [table aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) here, but they're not needed (they just arguably make the query a bit cleaner).